# Documentation #1005 - Can't create table 'comparein' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql

Where is the problem? i am trying to create the table comparein using the composed primary key from the table Episodi but there should be a problem that i can t see..
the primary key from the table is a combination of "numero" and "titolo_episodio"

```
create table Autori(
  id_autore int auto_increment primary key,
  nome varchar(15) not null,
  cognome varchar(15) not null,
  nome_arte varchar (15)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 create table Serie(
  nome varchar(25) primary key,
  id_autore int(6),
descrizione varchar(400),
  FOREIGN KEY (id_autore)REFERENCES Autori(id_autore)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 create table Episodi(
  titolo_episodio varchar(25) not null,
numero int not null,
  durata time not null,
  data_trasmissione date not null,
  nome_serie varchar(25),
PRIMARY KEY(titolo_episodio,numero),
  FOREIGN KEY (nome_serie)REFERENCES Serie(nome)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

  create table Personaggi(
  id_pers int auto_increment primary key,
  nome varchar(15) not null,
  cognome varchar(15),
  nazionalita varchar (15),
  nome_serie varchar(25),
   FOREIGN KEY (nome_serie)REFERENCES Serie(nome)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Utenti(
nickname varchar(15) primary key,
nazionalita varchar(15) not null,
mail varchar(25) not null,
pwd varchar(15) not null,
amministratore bool default 0 not null
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

create table Generi(
  genere varchar(15) primary key
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB;

 create table comparein(
  id_pers int not null,
  numero int not null,
titolo_episodio varchar(25),
 FOREIGN KEY (id_pers)REFERENCES Personaggi(id_pers),
 FOREIGN KEY (numero,titolo_episodio)REFERENCES Episodi(numero,titolo_episodio),
 primary key(id_pers,numero,titolo_episodio)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to reference the PK columns in the same order as the primary key was defined. So instead of

```
FOREIGN KEY (numero,titolo_episodio)REFERENCES Episodi(numero,titolo_episodio)
```

use

```
FOREIGN KEY (titolo_episodio, numero) REFERENCES Episodi(titolo_episodio, numero)
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/363bd